# Valgrind output when process is stopped using SIGINT

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

We have a huge application where some parts(threads) does not do clean shutdown, so memory is not explicitly released in the destructors because they are never called. So I am testing the application using valgrind by interrupting the process using Ctrl + C(SIGINT) command which somehow stops the process.  Valgrind shows lots of leaks(Definitely and possibly leaked).  I am running valgrind with following options

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file="valgrind5.out" -v ./MyProcess
```

I have two questions regarding this

1. And in the valgrind output I can see very large number of traces with following output

==2833== 3,330 bytes in 99 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 33,556 of 34,381
==2833== 3,337 bytes in 58 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 33,557 of 34,381

Can I consider "definitely lost" as memory leaked when the process is stopped using SIGINT  in this case ?

2. Valgrind dumps all the information about leaks and jumps based on uninitialized variables only after process is stopeed.  I was assuming that valgrind can detect "definitely lost" memory leaks at runtime and are immediately printed on the console or valgrind log file. Is the assumption wrong ?

Comment: You need to catch sigint in your programm to call shutdown part.

Comment: Definitely lost is your mem leak, this is the memory not pointed by any pointer. Steal reachable can be explained by your brutal stop.

Comment: @Ôrel It's a huge application handled by many developers, so SIGINT disappears somewhere before it reaches our application and we are force killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Orel, the "definitely lost" are indeed relevant whether your application terminated normally or was interrupted by SIGINT.
valgrind does not display the leaks as soon as it sees them, however. I assume this is because detecting the leaks might take time, and should not be done too often.
If you want to display all leaks as soon as possible, you could try using the Boehm-Weiser garbage collection library (http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) in such a mode that it doesn't actually frees the memory, but simply report what it thinks are no longer accessible objects.
This is of course a non-trivial effort, but it might be worth it.

You might also start using unique_ptr<> and shared_ptr<> a bit more, so that the memory is freed automatically. And also wrapping things in a class, for instance to ensure that the destructor frees the memory and closes file handles.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Since our our codebase is large and is developed by many developers with different skill set and with misuse of C++11 (like lambdas) even using unique_ptr<> and shared_ptr<> creates some issues like accessing invalid memory.

Comment: I would be interested to know of such a scenario in the case of shared_ptr<>, though ? By definition, they do not free memory while there is at least one such ptr around. You can combine this with weak_ptr if you just want to monitor memory while not prevent its deallocation. In this case, the pointer will be reset to null when the memory is freed.

Comment: One issues which I observed is passing shared_ptr by reference inside a lambda which is executed asynchronously. So by the time lambda is invoked object pointed by shared_ptr no longer exists